# Deleting files doesn't free up space

Tags: macos, disk-space, file

I moved away (to an external drive) about 30 GB of files from a drive (startup disk) that had 60 GB of free space.  After the move it still shows only 60 GB of free space, not 90, as I would expect.  The trash is emptied.

I tried rebooting and verifying the disk (no problems found), but it didn't change anything.

How can I diagnose and fix the problem?

Note: [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97723/resume-file-move-after-finder-crash-unmoved-items-appear-washed-out) is what happened during the move.  I deleted the "washed out" items and repeated the move.

---

**Update:** The space was being taken up by Time Machine's Mobile Backups feature. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/44329/31058) has solved the problem.

Comment: you could try `Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility` Select your Volume and perform `First Aid > Repair Disk`

Comment: @hoss "Repair Disk" is not available, but "Verify" is.  I did run that, and it said that no problems were found.

Answer (score 1):

The washed out appearance happened to me once on a failed copy, in my case the files all had an improper creation date. In fact changing the date on the file fixed the issue for me. I think I used the info on this page to change the created date of the files. http://blog.grapii.com/2010/07/change-a-files-creationmodified-date-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking there's a permissions issue with the faded icons.

Maybe open a terminal and try to sudo rm -r whatever is left?

Comment: The command is `rm -rd <path>` but be *VERY* careful as using `/` as your path will attempt to remove your whole drive, and sadness will prevail.

Comment: The faded icons, mentioned in the other question, appeared on the external drive, not on the drive where the space wasn't freed.  As far as I can tell, the files are now deleted from the internal drive.  They don't show in the Finder and they don't show with `ls -a`.  Yet I still see only 60 GB free space instead of 90 GB.

Comment: Oh I see, empty your trash.

Comment: @hoss The question has always said "The trash is emptied."

Comment: @hoss man page says the -R (or equivalent -r) option automatically implies -d.  And yes, don't run it on / for chrissake

Comment: @Szabolcs ahh you mention anything about an external drive in this question.  Just said deleted from the startup disk